# OpenBSD Packet Filter firewall in Ubuntu

Tags: firewall, iptables

Is there a way to use [OpenBSD's Packet Filter firewall](http://www.openbsd.org/faq/pf/) in Ubuntu?

Comment: As a side note, have you looked at zentyal-firewall from the Ubuntu Software Center? Zentyal is a Linux small business server that can act as a Gateway, Unified Threat Manager, Office Server, Infrastructure Manager, Unified communications Server or a combination of them. One single, easy-to-use platform to manage all your network services.  zentyal-firewall module adds firewalling capabilities.

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately, no. PF is deeply integrated with the BSD, and porting it to Linux will need a lot of effort. You'll have to stick with netfilter (`iptables`).